# PyInstaller and FastAPI (maximum recursion depth exceeded)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, fastapi

I have a python service that uses **fastapi** as a web interface. I need to make an executable file and hence I am using **PyInstaller**.

I keep getting the following error:

```
File "..../miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/lib/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 2912, in _load_package
    self._load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)
File "..../miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/lib/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 2093, in _load_module
    m = self._load_package(fqname, pathname, packagepath)

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I added `import sys; sys.setrecursionlimit(50000)` to the original python file as well as in the spec but still getting the same problem.

The interesting thing is that I don't get that error if I don't use **fastapi** (It works with Flask for example). Looks like PyInstaller has  some issue with fastapi.

Does anybody have any idea how to solve this issue?

This is the code in my main python function:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn
app = FastAPI()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", workers=1, port=5000)
```

Comment: Did you try increasing the recursion limit even further? What happens in case you specify `100.000` or more?

Comment: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4406 This is a known issue. We're working on a fix.

Answer (score 7):

I also encountered the same problem today, and I found that the problem was in the [Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/install/) module.

I reinstalled it directly from the repository:

```sh
pip uninstall pydantic

pip install git+git://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic@master#egg=pydantic
# or with extras
pip install git+git://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic@master#egg=pydantic[email,typing_extensions]
```

This will solve the **maximum recursion depth** problem, but will encounter another problem in [Uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/):

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logging/config.py", line 388, in resolve
AttributeError: module 'uvicorn' has no attribute 'logging'
```

And I replaced [Uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/) with [Hypercorn](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/hypercorn/how_to_guides/api_usage.html) + [Uvloop](https://uvloop.readthedocs.io/user/index.html) and it works very well now.

Here is my final code:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import asyncio
    import uvloop
    from hypercorn.asyncio import serve
    from hypercorn.config import Config

    config = Config()
    config.bind = ["0.0.0.0:8000"]

    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    loop.run_until_complete(serve(app, config))
```

Comment: Thanks for this works great. If you want to continue using Uvicorn the answer here will fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64281002/pyinstaller-compiled-uvicorn-server-does-not-start-correctly

Answer (score 5):

Using @UFO answer I then also updated the PyInstaller to include the hidden modules

1. Uninstall `pydantic` and install from source. Hopefully this will update in the registry soon.

```
pip uninstall pydantic

pip install git+git://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic@master#egg=pydantic
# or with extras
pip install git+git://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic@master#egg=pydantic[email,typing_extensions]
```

2. Run `pyinstaller main.py`
3. Add these hidden imports to `.spec` file generated by `pyinstaller`

```
hiddenimports=[
                'uvicorn.logging',
                'uvicorn.loops',
                'uvicorn.loops.auto',
                'uvicorn.protocols',
                'uvicorn.protocols.http',
                'uvicorn.protocols.http.auto',
                'uvicorn.protocols.websockets',
                'uvicorn.protocols.websockets.auto',
                'uvicorn.lifespan',
                'uvicorn.lifespan.on',
            ]
```

4. Run `pyinstaller main.spec`

Ref:

`main.py`

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def root():
    return {"hello": "world"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```