# uvicorn and fastAPI with pyinstaller problem when uvicorn workers>1

Tags: python, pyinstaller, fastapi, uvicorn

I had checked
[PyInstaller and FastAPI (maximum recursion depth exceeded)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61491358/pyinstaller-and-fastapi-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded) and
[Pyinstaller-compiled Uvicorn server does not start correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64281002/pyinstaller-compiled-uvicorn-server-does-not-start-correctly)

FastAPI demo `main.py`:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def root():
    return {"hello": "world"}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=58000, reload=False)
```

Run pyinstaller first `pyinstaller -F main.py --clean` and add `hidden_imports` in spec:

```
hidden_imports=[
                'uvicorn.logging',
                'uvicorn.loops',
                'uvicorn.loops.auto',
                'uvicorn.protocols',
                'uvicorn.protocols.http',
                'uvicorn.protocols.http.auto',
                'uvicorn.protocols.websockets',
                'uvicorn.protocols.websockets.auto',
                'uvicorn.lifespan',
                'uvicorn.lifespan.on',
            ]
```

It works good, but the app must be string when workers greater than 1:

`WARNING:  You must pass the application as an import string to enable 'reload' or 'workers'.`

So I change to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=58000, reload=False, workers=2)
```

After doing that, I ran the app `dist/main` and it created many apps like below, using 100% CPUs and 100% memories rapidly:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3Glb.png)

Works on Python 3.8.3 and pyinstaller 4.0

Comment: must be `hiddenimports` instead of `hidden_imports` I believe

Answer (score 5):

It is important to call (on Windows) `mutiprocessing.freeze_support()` in the beginning, see official [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support).

```
import multiprocessing
...
...
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mutiprocessing.freeze_support()
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=58000, reload=False, workers=2)
```

Additionally, it might be needed to add the module `main` as a hidden import.

Comment: although official docs say it "has no effect when invoked on any operating system other than Windows",   it really works for my case: fastapi+uvicorn+pyinstaller+docker. without freeze_support, the docker container reboots infinitely

Comment: Can confirm. `freeze_support` fixes infinite recursion on ubuntu20.04 (python3.8; fastapi+uvicorn+pyinstaller).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an infinite recursion to me. I suspect the cause is related to the self-reference at `main:app` and some PyInstaller `sys` dark magic that sets `__name__` as `__main__`.

I recommend moving `app` into a separate module and referencing it from that module in `uvicorn.run()`:

```py
# app.py
from fastapi import FastAPI


app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def root():
    return {"hello": "world"}
```

```py
# main.py
import uvicorn


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("app:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=58000, reload=False, workers=2)
```

Also, don't forget to add `app.py` as a hidden import for PyInstaller:

```
hidden_imports=[
    'uvicorn.logging',
    'uvicorn.loops',
    'uvicorn.loops.auto',
    'uvicorn.protocols',
    'uvicorn.protocols.http',
    'uvicorn.protocols.http.auto',
    'uvicorn.protocols.websockets',
    'uvicorn.protocols.websockets.auto',
    'uvicorn.lifespan',
    'uvicorn.lifespan.on',
    'app',
]
```